# Extracting the inner text from span using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to scrap some data from a webpage into Excel using vba.

The html code is

```
<span id="lastPrice">300.21</span>
```

I want the number 300.21

I tried this but didn't work (returned nothing in st)

```
Dim st As String

st = htmldoc.getElementById("lastPrice").getElementsByTagName("span")(5).innerText
```

How can I get the desired output ?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements that use `"lastPrice"` as their `ID`?

Comment: No I don't  have.Here's the link https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=SBIN&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0

Comment: `document.getElementById("lastPrice").innerText` returns the correct number using the Chrome's Console.  Could you post more code or a download link?

Comment: It is taking appropriate value into price :)I realized it is causing a problem when 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Cells(1, 1).Value = price

Comment: No worries.  Please accept Kostas K. answer and close the question.

Comment: So how can I solve the above problem in my comment?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the actual problem.  Is `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Cells(1, 1).Value` formatted properly?

Comment: Cleared formatting.Still it is coming 22.How can this happen when price is storing correct value.

Comment: Debugged and it is printing the correct value to the cell in this mode.But when I am running the code it is printing 22.

Comment: @user3126632 your question contains exactly nothing that writes to any cell, and isn't about writing to a cell. If you have another question, ask another question. Give Kostas' answer the checkmark it deserves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim element as Object
Set element = htmldoc.getElementById("lastPrice")

Dim price as String
If Not element Is Nothing Then price = element.innerText
```

Comment: Where is this coming from? Is there an element showing 2200.00% anywhere on the page?

Comment: No I didn't find anything on the page

Comment: Here is the link to the page https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=SBIN&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0