# How to scrape from a website with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

The following is the code on the website that I am trying to scrape:

```htm
<span id="dgCompShare_Label19_5">Total UK</span>
</td><td>
<span id="dgCompShare_Label32_5">39.82%   </span>
</td><td>
<span id="dgCompShare_Label21_5">40.84%</span>
</td><td>
<span id="dgCompShare_Label22_5">35.84%</span>
</td><td>
<span id="dgCompShare_Label23_5">36.42%</span>
</td><td>
<span id="dgCompShare_Label24_5">34.96%</span>
</td>
```

```vb
Dim appIE As Object
Dim ccc As Object
Dim percent As Integer
Set ccc = appIE.document.getElementById("dgCompShare_Label23_5")
ccc.innerTEXT = percent
```

How do I scrape the `36.42%` using Excel VBA?

Comment: Try `debug.print ccc.InterTEXT`

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955755/extracting-the-inner-text-from-span-using-vba/44956013#44956013

Comment: @Kostas K Thank you!